# Using CSV file to add values to value map?

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis-2, widget

I'm trying to populate a value map in the edit widget with some values from a csv file.

Could anyone let me know what format the csv file has to be in? 
At the moment I have just a list of comma-separated values (in UTF-8 if that matters), but when i click on 'Load data from CSV file' and browse to the relevant file, nothing happens.

I am using QGIS 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a test by saving a simple text file in 4 different encoding formats:

- ANSI
- Unicode
- Unicode big endian
- UTF-8

I then took the above text files, imported them into Microsoft Excel (by dragging the text file), saved these as .csv files and tried to load them into the **Value Map** widget.

Interestingly, only the data from the **ANSI** and the **Unicode** csv files were loaded, the other 2 did not. I don't think the formatting has any effect, if you have multiple columns of data then QGIS will use the first column as *Value* and the remaining columns will be joined in the *Description* with each data separated by a comma.

Note that the first line of data in the csv file is ignored when loading it into the widget (perhaps QGIS assumes the first row is used as a header?). So I guess, at the moment, it does matter which encoding you use (I also used QGIS 2.6 to test this).

Comment: Plain Unicode worked for me too, thanks. A strange bit of behaviour as all my csv joins are in UTF-8 and qgis seems to handle them fine. Anyway, problem solved.